# Problems with casting a void** to a T**

Tags: c++, casting

TL;DR: I have a Derived** that I store as a in Lua as a void* userdata. Then I try to get it back as a Base** and stuff breaks. Is there anything I can do or is this all madness that's doomed to failure?

Details:

I'm passing some data back and forth between Lua and C++, and Lua requires the use of void* to store userdata (That I'm using Lua isn't too important, other than that it uses void pointers). Makes sense so far. Lets say I have three classes, `Base` and `Derived`, with `Derived` inheriting from `Base`. The userdata I feed to Lua is a pointer to a pointer, like so:

```
template <typename T>
void lua_push(L, T* obj) {
    T** ud = (T**)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(T*)); // Create a new userdata
    *ud = obj; // Set a pointer to my object
    // rest of the function setting up other stuff omitted
}
```

Of course, this is in a nice templated function, so I can pass any of my three types in this way. Later on I can use another templated function to get my userdata out of Lua, like so:

```
template <typename T>
T* lua_to(lua_State* L, int index) { 
    // there's normally a special metatable check here that ensures that 
    // this is the type I want, I've omitted it for this example
    return *(T**)lua_touserdata(L, index);
}
```

This works fine when I pass in and out the same type. I'm running into a problem though when trying to pull a `Derived` out as a `Base`.

In my specific case, I have a vector being stored on `Base`. I use `lua_push<Derived>(L, obj);` to push my object to Lua. Later, in another place I pull it out using `Base* obj = lua_to<Base>(L, i);`. I then `push_back` some stuff into my vector. Later on, another portion of code pulls out that exact same object (verified with pointer comparisons) except this time uses `Derived* obj = lua_to<Derived>(L, i);` My `Derived` object doesn't see that object that was pushed in. I believe I've narrowed this down to incorrect casting, and I'm probably corrupting some memory somewhere when I make my call to `push_back`

So my question is, is there a way to make that cast work right? I've tried the various flavors of casts. static_cast, dynamic_cast and reinterpret_cast don't seem to work, either giving me the same wrong answer or not compiling at all.

Specific example:

```
Base* b = lua_to<Base>(L, -1); // Both lua_to's looking at the same object
Derived* d = lua_to<Derived>(L, -1); // You can be double sure because the pointers in the output match
std::cout << "Base: " << b << " " << b->myVec.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Derived: " << d << " " << d->myVec.size() << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
Base: 0xa1fb470 1
Derived: 0xa1fb470 0
```

Comment: What exact errors are you getting?

Comment: When I run with the code I've posted I don't get any compiler errors. Like I said, when I try to view or iterate over the items in my vector I can't as it has a size of 0 if I'm looking at it from the point of view of the derived class. I'll edit my question with a clear example.

Comment: This is very hard to parse. How is the vector involved? What is the type of the object?

Comment: Beta: The important information is that I have a Base class with some data on it. I edit that data. Then, when I get back the original Derived object, my data isn't what I expect it to be. I added all the details because often in the past I've tried to simplify my examples and people complain that I didn't clearly explain what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is not safe.  When you cast `Base *` to `void *`, you should always cast `void *` back to `Base *` first and *then* cast it again to `Derived *`.  As so:

```
Derived *obj = ...;
Base** ud = reinterpret_cast<Base **>(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Base*)));
*ud = obj; // implicit cast Derived -> Base
...
Derived *obj = static_cast<Derived *>(*ud); // explicit Base -> Derived
```

Basically speaking,

```
Y -> X -> void* -> X -> Y (safe)
Y -> X -> void* -> Y (unsafe)
```

The reason for this is that the actual pointer value of two pointers pointing to the same object may be different if the two pointers have different types.  Whether it works depends on various factors such as inheritance and virtual functions.  (It always works in C since C doesn't have those facilities.)

Answer (score 2):

This is all very much up to the compiler you're using, but generally the pointer to a base class is the same as a pointer to a derived class. Doing a coercive cast shouldn't hurt anything. The only exception is when there is multiple inheritance involved; a pointer to one base class won't be the same as a pointer to another base class, even with the same object. The compiler needs to know the exact type of the original pointer to properly adjust it, and the cast to void* loses that information.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mark Ransom's answer you can also get problems with this kind of casting if Derived contains a virtual function and Base does not, but again this is compiler specific.

Comment: Hadn't considered that case; I suppose the vtable pointer always goes to the front of the object?

Comment: Yes, and since Base is non-virtual the compiler has to adjust the pointer when going from Base* to Derived* or vice versa.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: No, it doesn't. It's not even a given that there's a vtable pointer (e.g. if there's only one virtual function, you might as well inline the table). Even when there is one, some compilers put it last. I'm not sure but I think they may also put it at a negative(!) offset.